# Missing mysqld.sock file on linux server

Tags: mysql

I have this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

Anyone know what is wrong? It seems it isn't installing *mysqld.sock*, when I run `apt-get install mysql-server`. I tried `find / -name "mysqld.sock"` but it can't find anything. How can I get mysqld.sock?

In *errror.log* I've got this error.

> 2018-08-13 10:43:09 139999537754688 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 98: Address already in $2018-08-13 10:43:09 139999537754688 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ? 2018-08-13 10:43:09 139999537754688 [ERROR] Aborting

Answer (score 0):

After installation is completed, please run mysql_secure_installation command. This will ask you to set mysql root password and other security related options, including removing remote access to the root user and setting the root password.

Try the below commands,

```
 mysql_secure_installation
 systemctl start mysql
 systemctl enable mysql
```